# Как закрыть сокет если к нему не подключились за определённый промежуток времени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Есть функция которая ожидает когда к сокету подключатся несколько раз,
(в примере ниже - 4 раза)
Эта функция работает, но как сделать так чтобы если к сокету за минуту ничего не подключилось то функция завершалась

Код:

```
from socket import socket

def waitcon(num):
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 45686))
    sock.listen(num)
    for _ in range(num):
        sock.accept()
        print("Accepted")

waitcon(4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если это линукс, то тут просто - заводим таймер и запускаем. процедуру accept. По выходу с процедуры таймер сбрасываем. Если accept задерживается, то прервём его исключением. Код будет такой

```
from socket import socket
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("alarm", signum)
    raise OSError("No connection")

def waitcon(num):
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 45686))
    sock.listen(num)
    for _ in range(num):
        signal.alarm(5)
        try:
            sock.accept()
            print("Accepted")
        except OSError:
            print("sorry, no one wants to connect to you")
        signal.alarm(0);

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
waitcon(4)
```

адаптировано из документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Но в целом, в питоне есть батарейки из коробки:) И по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354476/python-socket-object-accept-time-out можно найти пример. Я его чуточку адаптировал, **но не проверял полностью** в отличии от первого примера.

```
import socket

tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpServer.settimeout(60) # timeout for listening
tcpServer.bind(('127.0.0.1', 45686)) # IP and PORT
tcpServer.listen(1)

stopped = False
retry = 0
while not stopped:
  if retry == 4:
    break
  try: 
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
  except socket.timeout:
    pass
  except:
    raise
  else:
    # work with the connection, create a thread etc.
  retry=retry+1
```